# asp.net data binding in literal

Tags: asp.net

Lets say we have the following in the default.aspx file

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%= TestMethod() %>" />
```

What needs to be defined in the default.aspx.cs file to make this work?

I tried to add a method called `TestMethod` to the `_Default` class which simply returned the string `Test`, but it didn't seem to work.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

AJ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the method being marked `public`...

i think you could also remove the `asp:Literal` altogether

example
your code

```
<p><asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%= TestMethod() %>" /></p>
```

could be

```
<p><%= TestMethod() %></p>
```

However if you are intent on using the Literal then please rather set it on page load.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.aspx

Regards.

Comment: Yes that was the problem it needed to be <%# and not <%=, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can get the same result by doing this

In your `.aspx` file

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltr1" />
```

And in your `aspx.cs` file

```
ltr1.text = TestMethod();
```

Comment: That's true, and it's what I often prefer do, but Sitnam's answer is what's meant by the term "data binding "